# PyMongo Upgradation issue

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I upgraded PyMongo. After that when I am using below command then I can see the latest version:

```bash
~$ sudo pip freeze |grep pymongo
pymongo==3.13.0
```

Whereas MongoDB log is showing old version

```
2023-03-31T06:31:09.336+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn39802] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:35286 conn39802: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", **version: "3.10.1"** }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "5.4.0-1096-aws" }, platform: "CPython 3.7.5.final.0" }
```

I have run application in the 3.13 version. I am expecting the latest version should implemented and return in the response.

Comment: Try completely uninstalling the previous version and then reinstall the new one.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and the install but now I was facing new error and upgrade process failed. The error has been mentioned a line that upgrade first PIP using below command, I used the same command to upgrade PIP as well PyMonmgo and it was successfully upgraded
sudo /site/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo /site/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pymongo==3.13.0

Comment: What is the new error you are facing now edit that in your question itself, as per your above comment i understood that now pip and py-mongo has been successfully upgraded

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall and the install but now I was facing new error and upgrade process failed. The error has been mentioned a line that upgrade first PIP using below command, I used the same command to upgrade PIP as well PyMonmgo and it was successfully upgraded
sudo /site/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo /site/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pymongo==3.13.0